# Can't create pages or posts as admin in new Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I've installed a new Wordpress 4.9.1 on a Debian 9 Linode running Nginx and PHP7. There are no plugins installed and the default theme, but for some reason I can't create/edit any pages or posts. When I go into wp-admin and select new page or post it goes to post-new.php, but there is no publish box or attributes box in either 1 or 2 column view.

I've enabled DEBUG and it shows no errors, I've even tried reinstalling with older versions back to 3.9 but I still get exactly the same problem. The web-server and PHP are all good, there's a Joomla and MediaWiki on there that are running fine.
[image]

Comment: are you using default wp theme? if not then use default wp theme comes with new WP. also if above doesn't work then empty your `functions.php` file of currently active theme and then start submitting post. also you can check `screen options` on right top to verify something related to box not appearing. if nothing works then please post screenshot of WP Admin and add in above description.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, I'm using the default theme and no plugins, it's an out-of-the-box installation.No info in screen options, both 1 or 2 column view have no publish options. Screenshot added.

Comment: in your screenshot I saw error, or warning. Do you really sure, that you use default theme? Because, as I can see, your theme requiring some plugins, but default wordpress themes don't do it. check theme part one more time. The problem may be with your theme+php version

Comment: seems like you have some errors with PHP-7 in WP. also rename empty your plugin folder and functions.php, make sure your current active theme should be 'twentyseventeen'.

Comment: This is not default theme. Any of default theme do not use TGMPA to install plugins. There must be some bug in theme and it rise error from vars.php

Answer (score 2):

Finally tracked this problem down, it wasn't PHP7, it was the Nginx fastcgi params! I still don't know exactly what wasn't working with them since they are working fine on other servers, but I changed to the Nginx default params and it fixed the problem.

```
location ~ \.php {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```